# Adding Select All to dropdown

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

This is my query:

```
 <cfquery name="qry" datasource="#variables.staffDs#">
  SELECT
    firstname + ' ' + surname name, userid, mobileno, extension
  FROM
    currentstaff
  WHERE
    (mobileno IS NOT NULL OR
     Left(LTrim(extension), 2) = '07')
 </cfquery>
```

This is my ColdFusion dropdown box:

```
  <select name="to" id="to">
  <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
  <option style="font-weight: bold" value="">Send to All</option>
  <cfoutput query="people">
    <option value="#qry.userid#">#qry.name#</option>
  </cfoutput>
  </select>
```

The names of all people are displayed in the dropdown box list.

What I'd like to do is add an option at the top of the dropdown box to 'Sent to All' to select all users and I'm not sure how to do this.

I'd like to incorporate any extra SQL I might need into my current query, if this is necessary.

Comment: is that work for you ? but make use that data type of the other field is string as i am doing '' for the other columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to change like this if possible , just add

```
Select 'Select All'
 union
```

to your query , final code like

```
 Select 'Select All','','',''
 union
 SELECT
    firstname + ' ' + surname name, userid, mobileno, extension
  FROM
    currentstaff
  WHERE
    (mobileno IS NOT NULL OR
     Left(LTrim(extension), 2) = '07')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select 'Select All', '','',''
 union
 SELECT
    firstname + ' ' + surname name, userid, mobileno, extension
  FROM
    currentstaff
  WHERE
    (mobileno IS NOT NULL OR
     Left(LTrim(extension), 2) = '07')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to do this in SQL, rather than in HTML, like your example shows? I've worked on systems where a 'Select All' or 'Please choose' is unioned into the query and the downside is that you cannot re-use that query for other purposes, because the query is now generating something that is only useful in an HTML dropdown. 
To my mind, getting a list of people is one concern and building a UI with those people and a 'Select All' option is a different concern.

Comment: define a findUsersWithMobilePhones() function, which executes and returns your existing query. That's now re-usable and can be used elsewhere. You can then use your existing Coldfusion code to display the list. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question and your existing code isn't working, all I'd do differently is move the SQL out into some kind of function or query object so it's described and re-usable. Perhaps also change the value of the all users option, as Matt Busche shows in his answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add the option to query, I'd add an extra option row into the HTML and when `SELECT ALL` is chosen I would update my query to not filter.

```
<select name="to" id="to">
  <option value=""> -- Select -- </option>
  <option value="ALL">SELECT ALL</option>
  <option style="font-weight: bold" value="">Send to All</option>
  <cfoutput query="people">
    <option value="#qry.userid#">#qry.name#</option>
  </cfoutput>
</select>
```